# How can i crop face outline using flutter firebase_ml_vision? any other way to achieve this? Thank you

Tags: flutter, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I am trying to make a flutter application that crops face from an image. I am using the firebase_ml_vision package to do this. Is there any method that by which I can crop only the face outline (not bounding box)?
Thank you, sorry if the question too silly I'm new to flutter.

Comment: Don't think there's an API in firebase_ml_vision for that. You will have to implement it in your app.

Comment: @DongChen Thanks for replying, I'm trying the face_contour class to get the face coordinates but it's returning an empty list. if you could tell me how can I use the face_contour class to get face coordinates, ill try to use those coordinates to crop the face. The bounding box function is returning coordinates but the face contour is returning nothing or I don't know how to use it. [link](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_ml_vision/latest/firebase_ml_vision/FaceContour-class.html).

Comment: You are welcome.  Have you tried firebase_ml_vision's flutter sample on face detection (https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_ml_vision/lib/src/face_detector.dart)? It has an example on how to use the face contour.